# How to get the number of subscribers in the group?

Tags: facebook

This can be done using FQL, but now it is not available. How can I get the number of subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to get the number, you have to browse through all members with the `/group-id/members` endpoint and count on your own: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/members/